# Changing what THIS is

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Is there a way to change what THIS point to?

```
class foo{...}

foo* fooinstance = new foo();
foo* otherfooinstance = new foo();

void
foo::bar(){
    this = otherfooinstance;
}

fooinstance->bar();
```

for those of you who are wondering in what case I would change the this pointer here is case. I had to do a tree recursion where I had to remove intermediate nodes.. for this example lets assume the intermediate nodes of removal have the title d. and these intermediate nodes only have one child. So in lisp notation if we have a tree like

(g (d (i 4)) (i 5))

the function removeIntermediates(tree) would in effect cause the above to become

(g (i 4) (i 5))

and the pseudo code for this IF the this pointer was reassignable would look like the following..

```
DTREE::removeIntermediates(){
    this = child(0); removeIntermediates();
}

TREE::removeIntermediates(){
    for each child { child->removeIntermediates();
}
```

I wanted to do this without knowing what the child node was therefore making code factorable into different functions for each node type and having a general function for other types. 
Sadly, I just ended up doing something like this..

```
TREE::removeIntermediates(){
    for each child { if(child->name == "d") {
        setchild(child->child(0));
        child->removeIntermediates();
    }
    else { child->removeIntermediates();}
}
```

Comment: Please use <pre> and <code> to highlight the code.

Comment: Please don't follows Dadam's advice.

Comment: @Dadam: Prefix code with 4 spaces to get the appropriate highlighting.

Comment: Select the code and press CTRL+K to format code.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for that. So far I've been using `pre` and `code` and never noticed missing highliting.

Comment: You can change `self` in Objective C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) forbids assignment to this in "9.3.2 The this pointer" by stating that "keyword this is a non-lvalue expression". Although, some compilers still allow assignment to this by using a certain compile-time switch, because at some point in early drafts C++ standard actually allowed assignment to "this".

Anyway, it is quite hard to imagine a case where you would actually want to do that and it is very likely that there is a clean and beautiful way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

No, `this` is not modifiable.

Conceptually that doesn't make sense, [what are you trying to accomplish](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)?

Comment: Actually it makes enough sense that once, in early C++, it was supported. That was before exceptions. Assigning 0 to `this` was then a way to signal that construction failed (but only practical in a dynamic allocation context).

Answer (score 2):

No, you should never, ever, set `this`.

If you need to point to different objects then define your own variable.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is an rvalue, not an lvalue.  The easiest way to think
of it is that it invokes compiler magic to access the object on
which the function was called.  You can't modify it any more
than you could modify the constant 3.

Historically, in very early versions of C++, you could modify
it, but only in the constructor, and only as the first thing in
the constructor: the functionality offered by this has been
subsumed by user defined operator new.  This was 20-15 years
ago, however.

What are you trying to do?  If you just want to access two
different objects from the same member function, that's no
problem: otherfooinstance-> should work, and will give you
access to the private members as well.

Comment: For those who are wondering what I was trying to do.. I was trying to traverse a tree and remove intermediate nodes. For example in lisp notation..

(t (d (i 4))

I wanted to replace all d nodes with its child without needing to know what it's child is. For example, for changing the this pointer allowed the pseudo code would look like this..

{
if( node == d ) this = child(0);
else {
  for child in subtrees{
   
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

The member method void foo::bar() { this = otherfooinstance; } will be compile like this:

void foo__bar(foo * const this) { this = otherfooinstance; }

**this** is a const pointer to calling foo instance, so you can't change it.
And change **this** is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" pointer doesn't really exist. That is, it's not stored somewhere with the object. Rather, when a method is called on an object the compiler passes the address of the object as an extra argument. So "this" only ever really appears on the stack while a method is executing.

So even if you did assign to "this" as in your example, your redirection to otherfooinstance would last only for the duration of the current bar() invocation.

Comment: I understand that the this pointer is constant but, Aren't pointers that are passed in as arguments keep their changes of the function even after the duration of bar?

For example,
    foo(BAR* bar){bar = NULL;}

    BARINSTANCE = BAR();  //BARINSTANCE IS NOT NULL;
    foo(BARINSTANCE);     //NOW BARINSTANCE IS NULL;

Comment: @Doboy: That's false. The value of the pointer is copied, and operated on independently within the function.