# Why can we assign to *this?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ ,whenever we call member function through an object ,it implicitly pass one argument to member function say **classname * const this** 
eg :

```
void SetID(int nID) { m_nID = nID; }
```

becomes:

```
void SetID(Simple* const this, int nID) { this->m_nID = nID; }
```

So now in below example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    int x;

public:
    Test(int x = 0) { this->x = x; }

    void change(Test* t) { *this = *t; }
    void print() { cout << "x = " << x << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Test ctest1(10);
    Test* ptest = new Test(20);
    ctest1.change(ptest);
    ctest1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

So as we know internally ctest1.change will pass this pointer which is const **(Test *const ptr)**. So how am i possible to change "this" to point to some other object . In abv example this now points to ptest

Also want to know what is difference between this and *this

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402189/changing-what-this-is)

Comment: @dolan. The *pointer* itself is `const`, always.  You can't do `this = 0`, even if the object pointed to is mutable

Comment: *Also want to know what is difference between `this` and `*this`*. This is the key. Read beginners books/documentation about C or C++ to learn this basic. This site is not for teaching you.

Answer (score 1):

> So how am i possible to change "this" to point to some other object

You can't; it always points to the object on which the member function was called, and it can't be changed. As you say, it behaves (more or less) like an extra parameter of type `Test * const` - with the `const` meaning you can't change the pointer to point to anything else.

> In abv example this now points to ptest

No it doesn't. `*this = *t` modifies the value of object that `this` points to, reassigning it with whatever `t` points to. It still points to the same object (with a new value) afterwards.

> Also want to know what is difference between `this` and `*this`

`this` is a pointer to the object; `*this` dereferences the pointer to access the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the assignment operator. You are not changing `this` to point to a different object, you are changing the memory that `this` is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

How can I change this to point to something else??

In plain English :: You couldn't do it and you shouldn't do it.

Reason is "this" for class X is "X *const this".

Comment: The English language is letting us down here. The phrase "change `this` to point to something else" is ambiguous. Does it mean we wish to leave the object unchanged, but arrange for the pointer to start pointing to another object? Or does it mean that we want the pointer to continue to point to the same object, but make a modification to that object